Efficient way to create an std::vector from a contiguous subset of another std::vector
I am currently receiving some data which is stored in an std::vector, and I am looking for an efficient way of dropping the first few indices of the data in this vector, which hold some header information, and storing the rest of the data in another vector. In other words my code looks something like this:
std::size_t len = 1000000000; //some big number
std::vector<std::uint8_t> input_data;
input_data.resize(len);

//the receive_data function takes a uint8_t pointer as input and writes in it len bytes of data
receive_data(input_data.data(), input_data.size()); 

std::size_t header_len=40;
std::vector<std::uint8_t> sliced_data;
sliced_data.resize(len-header_len);

//copy in a new vector all the data received, minus the header
std::copy(input_data.begin()+header_len, input_data.begin()+len, sliced_data.begin());

The problem with the above code is that it does an expensive memcopy in order to remove the tiny header and copy the remaining large chunk of data in sliced_data, which seems unnecessarily slow to me. Is there a way to create the new vector sliced_data, that contains all the data in input_data minus the header?
Is there an efficient way of doing this using C++17? Can std::move do this for example?
I know this would be trivial if I was dealing with uint8_t pointers, however in my case the sliced data needs to be stored in a new vector, where the first index points at the data in index header_len of input_data.
Thanks

std::move is not relevant here. But maybe you can use std::span  (which does not require copy) for sliced_data instead of std::vector.

How about a string view? Or a span? Or the range library (or the original range library that was used as a base for the C++ standard)?

How about std::vector::data and memcpy ?

You could use the constructor of std::vector which takes a range, expressed as two input iterators as arguments when you create sliced_data. This seems to me like it would be the most efficient way, and I think it has been available forever (or at least as long as std::vector has been available).

@StasSimonov how it that different than the std::copy the OP showed ?

@RobertHairgrove it will still copy the elements, so it's effectively the same as using std::copy.

Do you input_data to hold anything useful after creating sliced_data? (If not, then you can just modify input_data in place to remove the header.) If so, do you expect input_data and sliced_data to contain separate copies of the data, so that changes to one do not affect the other? If so, then your own requirements say that you need to copy. (If not, then you can use a span or a range.)

Taking over memory from std::vector

@wohlstad But the OP is calling resize which wouldn't be necessary if sliced_data was constructed with an iterator range. Without knowing more about the receive_data() function, which delivers all of the data, I don't think there is a way to avoid copying the data without running into memory management issues.

@RobertHairgrove the constructor you mentioned will also have to allocate the relevant memory, similarly to what resize is doing.

You could switch to a container like Boost's devector that allows you to erase the front elements without memcpy

Why not receive_data(input_data.data(), header_size); receive_data(input_data.data(), input_data.size());?

If an answer solves your problem @astrophobia you could click '✔' to mark it as an accepted answer. You can also upvote any helpful answer (voting and accepting is separate). See here: What should I do when someone answers my question?.

If you have c++ 23, std::start_lifetime_as exists to overlay structure upon and take ownership of a raw block of data.

It's not possible with std::vector. A std::vector owns the data and manages it exclusively. Initializing it with some external data will always require a copy.
Also note that std::move is not relevant here:
If you move from input_data itself, the whole data will be moved.
And since the elements themselves are uint8_t moving the elements (e.g. using std::move_iterator) is the same as copying so that's also not helpful.
But if you have access to C++20, you can use std::span which is a lightweight non-owning class.
It does not require any copy when initialized from input_data:
#include <span>
//...
std::span<std::uint8_t> sliced_data(input_data.begin() + header_len, len-header_len);

You will need to update any method that currently accepts sliced_data, but it might be worth it performance-wise.
If you are limited to C++17, you might be able to use std::string_view which is similar in concept (but it's oriented to strings and so it's a bit convoluted to use it for uint8_t data).

Do note that move_iterators are a thing so you can move objects from one vector to another or from the source into the vector.  Not that it helps here since a move or a copy is the same thing for uint8_t

@NathanOliver good to know about move_iterator - I was not familiar with it (I will add a mention of move_iterator to my answer). But yes as I already wrote I agree that any kind of move it not helpful for uint8_t elements.

There is no way to do this using std::vector, but you can do it with shared_ptr. You just need to store the size separately, so you might want to wrap this technique into a class.
It goes something like this. Since you tagged C++17, you can use shared_ptr this way. I'm using make_shared_for_overwrite, which is C++20, but you can work around that by using raw new[].
std::size_t len = 1000000000; //some big number
auto input_data = std::make_shared_for_overwrite<std::uint8_t[]>(len);

//the receive_data function takes a uint8_t pointer as input and writes in it len bytes of data
receive_data(input_data.get(), len); 

std::size_t header_len=40;
std::size_t data_len = len - header_len;
std::shared_ptr<std::uint8_t[]> sliced_data(input_data, input_data.get() + header_len);

// Now sliced_data points to the actual data without the header.
// The buffer will be deallocated once all shared_ptrs to it have been destroyed.

